# PnP Add-Alert does not work as I´m expected

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want create an alert via Powershell PNP on a SharePoint-Library which runs daily at 18:00 (6:00 pm CET)

This is my not working line:

```
 Add-PnPAlert -Title "Test-Alert" -List "Steuerberatung" -User "c:0t.c|tenant|bc76e8d8-eeda-40eb-a4d7-532f9550a1f3" -Frequency Daily -ChangeType All  -Time (Get-Date -Format "HH:mm" -Hour 18  -Minute 00 -Second 00)
```

What do I wrong?

Comment: Are you a site admin or owner where you are trying to add alert? Are you getting any error or the alert emails are not sent to user?

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP
I´m an admin and owner as well.  No error is shown. It just do not send any alerts

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full code. For example, to create an alert for “Documents” on the site URL “https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/Branding” and send daily email alerts to the user with the email address “Steve@Crescent.com” for all changes, you can use the following command:

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/Branding"
$UserId= "i:0#.f|membership|Steve@crescent.com"
 
Try {
    #Connect to PnP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
  
    #Create an Alert
    Add-PnPAlert -Title "Documents Alert" -List "Documents" -User $UserId -Frequency Daily -ChangeType All
       
    Write-host "New Alert has been Created for the given user!" -f Green   
}
Catch {
    Write-host -f Red "Error:" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Reference: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/10/sharepoint-online-create-alerts-using-powershell.html#ixzz8RnYynztY

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you?